# Comment peut-on analyser la phrase « c’est ce qu’elle avait l’air de me reprocher » ?

Tags: sens, pronoms-relatifs

> Elle m’a regardé: «Tu ne veux pas savoir ce que j’ai à faire?» Je
>   voulais bien le savoir, mais je n’y avais pas pensé et **c’est ce
>   qu’elle avait l’air de me reprocher**.

Quel part joue le « ce que » en ce qui concerne le verbe principal? L'objet direct est « l'air », donc comment est-il relié au verbe? Quel est le sens de l'expression?

Comment: The "ce" is a direct object of the verb "reprocher": "... and that's what she was apparently criticising me for."

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que l'incompréhension vient du verbe "avoir l'air" qui signifie sembler (c'est l'air de "un air de famille, de ressemblance" et non celui de l'air pur des montagnes). "Avoir l'air" est parfois considéré comme un verbe à part entière en français, et il n'est pas suivi d'un complément d'objet direct, mais d'un attribut du sujet, car c'est un verbe d'état.

Sinon, la réponse d'Alone-zee est correcte : sans subordonnée, on dirait "elle avait l'air de me reprocher ça", par exemple.